# RecyclerView - change item value only if item satisfies a condition?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am having an issue with RecyclerView - in onBindViewHolder(), when I make a condition for each item in the list (going through the whole list, position by position), and want to change the item text value, it doesn't work. I assume that's because RecyclerView recycles items.
`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TimeViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val time = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timeTextView)

    val item = list[position]

    //items in list: "11aa", "11bb", "11cc"
    if (item.value.substring(0, 2).toInt() == 11 && item.value.substring(2,4) == "bb") {
       time.text = "true"
     } else {
       time.text="false"
     } 
    // list should be shown as: "false", "true", "false"


    if (item.value.substring(0,2).toInt() == 11 && item.value.substring(2,4) == "aa") {
      time.text="true"
    } else {
       time.text="false"
    }
      //list should be shown as: "true", "false", "false"
```

```
`

Example: item is "11bb" -> show true, all other items should be false (including "11aa")
         item is "11aa" -> show true, all other items are false (including "11bb")

I would greatly appreciate any suggestion!

I tried the else condition, so it is not only "if" without other possible outcome, still doesn't work
```

Comment: You cannot assume that `onBindViewHolder()` will go through your list position by position. You need have your list transformed and ready to be consumed by the adapter (unless your dataset is really long and you have to start considering lazy loading).

Comment: Can you share you xml of RecyclerView. From the shared code I can see that you have called findViewById in onBindViewHolder which is not correct.  findViewById should be called in inner ViewHolder class like this                   class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView

        init {
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every item in the list, you're doing **two** checks. First you check if `item` is `"11bb"` and display *true* or *false*. But **then** you throw that result out the window by checking if it's `"11aa"` instead, and display *true* or *false* based on that.

The end result is *each item* displays *true* if it's `"11aa"`, otherwise it shows *false*.

---

Here's what you said you wanted in your question:

```
Example: item is "11bb" -> show true, all other items should be false (including "11aa")
         item is "11aa" -> show true, all other items are false (including "11bb")
```

So it sounds like you want a *single* item to display *true*, and displaying that sets the others to *false*, right?

Those two rules you've provided contradict each other - what if you have *both* `"11aa"` *and* `"11bb"` in your data, like your example does?

> `//items in list: "11aa", "11bb", "11cc"`

Which one should show *true*? The first one in the list, `"11aa"`? Or does a later one override the earlier one, so `"11bb"`? What's the rule for resolving this?

---

Here's a way you can do it, assuming you want the first one in the list.

First, you need a function to *set* your adapter's data. This is so you can check through it, and work out in advance which item needs to be set to *true*:

```
// inside your adapter

// your internal data - private so anything setting the data -has to- go through
// the setter function below. 
private var items: List<String>

// index of the item that should be displayed as true, or null if there isn't one
// (I'm storing an index instead of the item in case there are duplicates in the list)
private val trueItemPosition: Int? = null

fun setData(newData: List<String>) { 
    // set the new data
    items = newData
    // store the index of the first item that matches your rules, or null if none do
    val matchedIndex = items.indexOfFirst(::matchesRule)
    trueItemPosition = if (matchedIndex == -1) null else matchedIndex
    
    // always refresh after setting data!
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

// you don't need to do any of that Int conversion or substring stuff, just match the string!
private fun matchesRule(item: String) = when {
    item.startsWith("11aa") -> true
    item.startsWith("11bb") -> true
    else -> false
}
```

Then in `onBindViewHolder` you can decide what to do depending on the current item's `position` and the value of `trueItemPosition`:

```
// in onBindViewHolder

when(trueItemPosition) {
    null -> {
        // display your item normally - there's no 11aa or 11bb in the list
    }
    position -> {
        // this item is the matching one
        time.text = "true"
    }
    else -> {
        // there's a matching item, but this isn't it
        time.text = "false"
    }
}
```

And that's pretty much it! You can use `indexOfLast` if you want the *last* matching item to take precedence, and you could make separate functions for the different rule matchers if you want, say, a `11aa` anywhere in the list to take precedence over any `11bb`s. Just run them one after another on the whole data set in order of preference, until you get a matching index.

---

Like I said, this *relies on* you setting *all* your data through that `setData` function, so it can work things out before you display anything. That includes the initial data you provide - so if you're passing data in as a constructor parameter, that can't be a property and you need to call `setData` with that parameter in an `init` block:

```
class MyAdapter(
    ...
    data: List<String> // not a val/var, we're just using this temporarily
    ... {

    init {
        // set the internal data through the setter
        setData(data)
    }


}
```

and that should do it!

---

**edit** If you need arbitrary matching indices (other than *first* or *last*) you'll need to code that logic - it's probably best to put it in a function:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.matchingIndexNumber(ordinal: Int, predicate: (T) -> Boolean) =
    mapIndexedNotNull { i, item -> if (predicate(item)) i else null }
        .getOrNull(ordinal - 1) ?: -1
```

Now you can call `items.matchingIndexNumber(2, ::matchesRule)` to get the *2nd* match's index, etc.

By the way, I kinda glossed over this, but the reason I used indices was because they're guaranteed to be unique - if you *know* all your items will be unique objects (i.e. none of them return *true* for `equals` when compared to the other items) then you can drop the indices entirely, and just store the matching object:

```
// potentially store the important -item- itself
private val trueItem: String? = null

fun setData(newData: List<String>) { 
    ...
    // just set the first item that matches, or null if nothing matches
    trueItem = items.first(::matchesRule)
    ...
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TimeViewHolder, position: Int) {
    ...
    when(trueItem) {
        null -> // no important item in list - display this normally
        item -> // this item is the important one
        else -> // there's an important item, this isn't it
    }
    ...
}
```

Which is a whole lot simpler! The indices approach works no matter what, but if your items are all unique, this is the way I'd go. (If they're not, e.g. you have two `"11aa"` strings, they'll both match `trueItem` in that `when` block so they'll both show *true* or whatever)

Anyway, if you're working with the items themselves instead of having to juggle indices and return *-1* for missing stuff, you can just do this:

```
// get the 3rd matching item
trueItem = items.filter(::matchesRule).getOrNull(3)
// or
trueItem = items.filter(::matchesRule).drop(2).firstOrNull()

// or if you want the 3rd item, but if there isn't one you want the 2nd, and so on
trueItem = items.filter(::matchesRule).take(3).lastOrNull()
```

There are way more options in the standard library for working with the collection of items directly, it's much more flexible, so I'd recommend it if you can!

(You could also do the `take(count).lastOrNull()` trick in that function I wrote if you do want/need to stick with the indices though)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer and explanation! 
I will try doing that in an hour and will let you know if it works.
The examples I've written here are simplified, the actual code is trying to highlight the current time in the time slider where you have only 30min steps so if the current time is ie 14:12, highlight 14:00, or if the current time is 14:37, highlight 14:30.

Comment: @NatašaAndžić ah ok - yeah you'll need a more complex matcher function then, but it should be structured the same! The `matchesRule` function just needs to work out if an item is the important one or not, everything else is just based around the first item that gets a *true* result from that

Comment: You have saved my nerves and this weekend, I've been working on this for days.... thanks mate! <3

Comment: indexOfFirst, indexOfLast were super useful

Comment: @astro.zombi hey no worries, enjoy yr weekend!

Comment: any idea how to get indexOfSecond and indexOfThird? since those functions don't exist

Comment: @astro.zombi I've added a bit to the answer about it